# echo <a href="#"></a> in php

Tags: php, anchor, echo

how to echo anchor in php when anchor has `#` as its href i has search a lot in net and i havent found similar probnlem so i cant fint any possible solution to this problem.

i tried putting he `#` inside `"''"` but its not working when i just do thre regular anchor like `<a href="#"></a>` all characters following the `#` sign will become comments.

```
echo "<a href="#" >".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a>";
```

Comment: escape double quotes, its already shown on the syntax highlighter :)

Comment: i see now i understand how to escape double quotes now

Comment: All the answers here are correct, but I see no reason why single quotes wouldn't solve the problem. `echo "<a href='#' >".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a>";` should work fine.

Comment: Your edit provides more insight. Use `'#'` not `"'#'"`.

Comment: @MarkM sorry i think my post is misleading i am wrong what i tried is putting it like this "'#'" and not '#' i havent tried it like the way you commented my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `backslashes \ \` to the attribute

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" >".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a>";
```

Comment: Someone downvoted even if my answer is correct.  WOW!

Comment: i did not i upvoted it..actually im picking it as the correct answer since you were the first i just pick it now because it says i have to wait for a few minutes

Comment: @satinekianne If my answer solves your problem. Accept my answer to let others know yours is already solved.

Comment: @satinekianne Glad to help you. I know you'll do the same for someone else

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of these. I'm not a fan of \"

```
echo "<a href=\"#\">{$value['searchresultwhat']}</a>";
echo "<a href='#'>{$value['searchresultwhat']}</a>";
```

[Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: I don't want to be harsh but why do you feel the need to post this answer when there are already four others that provide exactly what you have here?

Comment: I didn't see a answer with braces around the variable. I still don't maybe something is cached on my mobile app.

Comment: @MarkM yeah still not seeing anyone else mentioning it. Here is a link if someone wants to know more about it Complex (curly) syntax http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the double quotes. Try with

```
echo "<a href=\"#\">".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
echo "<a href='#' >".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a>";
```

Comment: This would be my answer too, but OP said this was already tried.

Comment: @MarkM sorry i think my post is misleading i am wrong what i tried is putting it like this `"'#'"` and not `'#'` i havent tried it like the way you commented my bad

Comment: @satinekianne, ok whatever it is i think your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 echo "<a href='#' >".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a>";
```

OR

```
 echo "<a href=\"#\" >".$value['searchresultwhat']."</a>";
```

OR

```
 echo '<a href="#" >'.$value['searchresultwhat'].'</a>';
```

OR

```
 <a href="#" ><?= $value['searchresultwhat'] ?></a>;
```

OR

```
 <a href="#" ><?php echo $value['searchresultwhat'] ?></a>;
```